# simple usage of c++ string length() function not compiling

Tags: c++, eclipse, string

I'm doing a very basic usage of std::string in c++ in Eclipse, and can't figure out why it's not working.

The sample code:

```
std::string str = "hello";
cout << str << ":" str.length();
```

The code is not compiling with the following error: `Method 'length' could not be resolved`

Why?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a '<<'

`cout << str << ":" << str.length();`

Comment: @Nnp If that's the case, I would assume that it's something eclipse (which is an IDE, and not a compiler).  I would recommend trying to compile it.  The code (with the error fixed), compiles here at https://ideone.com/GbCRip

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you #include  at the top of your file.  However, I would think you would get an error about not being able to resolve std::string if you didn't.